# Change ESP8266 I2S pins

Tags: esp8266, pins, i2s

On ESP8266 the default pins for I2S are:
Data bits (SD) = GPIO3/RX0,
Data bit-clock (SCK) = GPIO15,
Word select (WS) = GPIO2/TX1

However in my application Im using these pins for another purpose. Is there a way how to set I2S pins to different GPIOs?

Comment: What does the data sheet / programmers manual say?   What software approach are you using (ESP-IDF, Arduino, or other) and does it offer any relevant configuration APIs?

Comment: data sheet doesnt say anything about that

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late but I think you can't.
ESP8266 datasheet shows one I2S interface where pins are set, not configurable.
Maybe you can move your other things if they are used as GPIOs.
Good luck